# Does pip install install all dependencies?

Tags: pip

Say the foo package has files that import files and methods from the bar package. If I pip install foo, will it automatically install bar, or do I need to also pip install bar?

Answer (score 0):

It will install everything that is Python code. Try it yourself for example with Flask which has several dependencies

```
pip install flask
```

The `time` module that was mentioned in a comment is part of Python itself (its standard library) and will never need to be installed.

Some Python libraries are wrappers around other programs, like `pymediainfo`. So to use it you would still be required to install MediaInfo separately outside of pip.

Comment: So to be clear: all user-created, non-Python system packages are installed when using pip install? (e.g.: foo and bar would be installed, but if python's time package was used, it wouldn't be installed?).